# Как в mongoose сделать ++ полю?

Tags: mongoose

в SQL можно сделать инкремент полю одним запросом

```
UPDATE myTable SET field = field + 1
```

как такого же добиться в mongoose?

update делаю так, но как туда добавить инкремент?

```
var _id = 1, _field = 5;
model.update({ id : _id }, { field : _field });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь оператором [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

```
model.update({ groupId : gid }, {$inc: {field:1}}, {multi: true});
```

Comment: Ваш пример почему то обновляет только 1ую запись, как реализовать это для нескольких строк? P.S. ищу не по id, а по groupId

Comment: Мой пример тут ни при чём, он взят из вашего. Нужна опция `multi`

Comment: спасибо, заработало